# Flutter Glassfy Identify the subscriber

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription

Glassfy automatically tries to identify the subscriber based on information on the purchases received by the SDK.

The permissions object has two parameters that help to uniquely identify the subscriber:

> **subscriberId** : identifies the subscriber and is connected with the purchases from the store. If a user reinstalls an app the subscriberId remains the same. Due to the way app stores work it is not possible to disassociate a subscriber from their AppStore / PlayStore account so this identifier will remain the same. The subscriberId may change if a user without a purchase removes and reinstalls the app.

> **installationId**: identifies the current installation of the application and is regenerated every time the app is reinstalled or installed on a different device.

it keeps starting from the purchase page even though i restart the run even though i have a subscription

```
final isPremium = context.watch<GlassfyProvider>().isPremium;

return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            buildEntitlement(isPremium),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: fetchOffers,
              child: const Text('Plans'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


Widget buildEntitlement(bool isPremium) => isPremium
      ? buildEntitlementIcon(
          text: 'You are on Paid plan',
          icon: Icons.paid,
          color: Colors.green,
        )
      : buildEntitlementIcon(
          text: 'You are on Free plan',
          icon: Icons.lock,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
Widget buildEntitlementIcon({
    required String text,
    required IconData icon,
    required Color color,
}) =>
      Column(
        children: [
          Icon(icon, color: color, size: 100),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          Text(text),
        ],
      );
```